# how can I change date/time in jelastic?

Tags: jelastic

we have jelastic, and even with VDS, all changes made in date are not applied to my environments.

how can I change date/time in jelastic?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The VDS is a standalone system. The other servers in your environment are separate.

If you want to change the timezone for your other servers, you should ask your hosting provider to do it. However, in most cases you can also specify a timezone at application level (e.g. [How to set a JVM TimeZone Properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493749/how-to-set-a-jvm-timezone-properly) [Managing timezones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325716/managing-timezones) etc.), so system time would only be relevant for log files and cron.

Comment: In `PHP` I use **date_default_timezone_set**

Comment: That works for managing timezone within your PHP app, but you need to be careful because it will not alter the timezone at OS level (meaning the timezone used for log files and cron jobs can't be changed this way).

Answer (score 0):

With Jelastic, you can use the add-on **"TimeZone Change"** from the MarketPlace.

[image: jelastic marketplace timezone update for date management]

Note : on some docker containers it will not work

*See official documentation : https://docs.jelastic.com/timezone-management*